# Linear and Affine functions

Tags: linear-transformations, affine-geometry

Wanted to be clear on my understanding on affine functions, and if we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and a vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, I know an affine map is given by:
$$f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, f(x) = Ax + c  $$
and if $c$ happens to be the $0$ vector, then the map/function would be linear. So going based of this definition and my understanding of it, I would imagine the following three properties to be true?

- For every $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and the vectors $v_1, v_2 \in
     R^{m}$, a linear function should satisfy the property: $f(\gamma v_1
   + v_2) = \gamma f(v_1) + f(v_2)$.
- Assuming $m=n$, and $A$ nonsingular, then a linear function should
  preserve the length of the argument $||f(x)|| = ||x||$.
- Assuming $m=n$, and $A$ nonsingular, then an affine function should
  be nonsingular/invertible and its inverse is of the form/given by the function,
  $f^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, f^{-1}(x) = A^{-1}(x
     - c)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First point

This is correct.

As you correctly pointed out, if $f$ is linear, then $f(x)=Ax$ for some $n\times m$ matrix $A$.

In this case we have
\begin{align}
f(\gamma v_1+v_2) & = A(\gamma v_1+v_2) \\
                  & = A(\gamma v_1)+Av_2 \\
                  & = \gamma Av_1+Av_2 \\ 
                  & = \gamma f(v_1)+f(v_2).
\end{align}

---

### Hint for the second point

Consider $f\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x)=Ax$ where
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
k & 0 & 0 \\
0 & k & 0\\
0 & 0 & k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $k\neq 0,1$.

Will this preserve length? Where will the vector $$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}$$ get mapped? And what will the length of its image be?

---

### Third point

Provided $A$ is invertible, yes, the affine function will be invertible with the inverse you described.

Comment: For the second point the length of (1,0,0) does not get preserved as it gets scaled by k? Which should mean the second point is actually not correct?

Comment: @User_13 Indeed. So your statement is not, in general, true.